# Authorizing service account with oauth2 using python for Google Play Developer API

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-oauth, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to authorize a service account using oauth2 through the google-client-api python library.  I am ultimately wanting to verify in-app purchases.

This is my code:

```
   SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
   SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'google.api.json'

   credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

   http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

   service = build(
       serviceName='androidpublisher',
       version='v2',
       credentials=credentials
   )
   req = service.purchases().products().get(
            packageName=package,
            productId=product,
            token=token
        )

   response = req.execute()
```

I get this message back:

```
...returned "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
```

My project ID is absolutely linked; my service account is absolutely connected in the Google Play Console as a user with the correct permissions for this project.  When I log the above code, I am getting the project ID that is linked.

The token (not access token, but in-app purchase token) is from a test purchase of my personal Google account (just recently Google finally opened up developer's accounts for test purchases!).  And the sku for my test purchase is the actual sku that I am going to sell to the app users.

I am at a loss.  There is so much conflicting information on how to do what I am trying to achieve.  For shame, Google! For Shame!  The docs are lacking, to say the least.  (I mean they have good information, it is just scattered all over the place).

I would love any advice on this.  I am at a loss and can't get past the above error message.

**EDIT**:  **My code was correct above;  see my answer for the real cause.**

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this problem with the help of this link [here](https://dev.to/sandris/androidpublisher--projectnotlinked-error-43c7).

I had created my in-app purchase prior to linking my project.  Creating a new in-app purchase solved the problem.  On another note:  That error message is sure misleading.

Also on a semi-unrelated note, while I was doing this I struggled with understanding if I needed to get and use an **access_token** with my service account and authorize this way.  I focused too long on this thinking this was the issue.  **In the end, using my service account, and authorizing with JWT is enough.**  You do **not** need to do anything with access tokens or refreshing them as seen in the code above for authorization to work.  I thought I would add this to the answer because it would have saved me hours had I known this as I went down the wrong path far too long on the above error message.

Comment: Does this solution work with the old product or only with the new one?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte I don't know what you mean "the old product", but this is the only attempt I have made doing this so I probably don't have an answer for you unfortunately.  I can only recommend using an in app product created after linking your project.

Comment: Sorry I didn't expressed myself so well there, but the "old product" I mean is the one you've mentioned here: "I had created my in-app purchase prior to linking my project.". What I would like to know is, can you fetch information from this particular product?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte Ah, I think I know what you mean.  This was a brand new product (in app item) that I have not sold before.  So there was no information tied to it yet.    So this might not be helpful to you then.

Comment: Hello there, again, I thought that it would be nice to share that I successfully called the API after all. For some reason that I don't know it worked, and all that I had to do was to wait for a least 2 days for it to understand that everything was fine ;/ .
Also, thanks for the fast answer ;D